# HBase Java vs REST

Tags: java, exception, hbase

I have a funny one. In HBase using the following code I get values back, not the actual values but locations of the values.

When I run the query using the HBase Shell it works fine, works in REST but not in Java. The only difference I can see is the setting of the Zookeeper Quorum, I may be setting the HBase servers, would this cause this issue?

**REST Interface**  -- Works

```
public static String get(String serialNumber, String remoteHost,
            String remoteTable, int remotePort) {

        RemoteHTable table = null;
        Get g = new Get(serialNumber.getBytes());
        Result res = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating remote table");
            table = new RemoteHTable(new Client(new Cluster().add(remoteHost,
                    remotePort)), remoteTable);
            res = table.get(g);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                table.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
```

Java Interface

```
public static String javaGet (String serialNumber) throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException{
          Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
          conf.clear();
          conf.addResource("hbase-site.xml");
          conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","values");
          conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
          conf.set("hbase.master", "hostName:6000");
          conf.set("hbase.client.retries.number", Integer.toString(1));
          conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", Integer.toString(60000));
          conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", Integer.toString(1));
          HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);



          HTable table = new HTable(conf, "partyIdData");
          // The following line works and prints out data
          System.out.println(table.getTableDescriptor());

          Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(serialNumber.toString()));

           // A WrongRegionException is thrown by the following line
           Result r = table.get(g);  

            return "make it to here";
      }
```

Comment: i don't think so it is a HBase settings since you get the correct values from the shell and the REST API.

Comment: I've tried this on a smaller Hbase instance on a single node VM with a subset of the same data and all three work fine